# Camping in Torres del Paine in May

Tags: camping, chile, torres-del-paine

Is it possible to do the W-trek in Torres del Paine from April 30 to May 4 (Camping. No refugio)?

If the campsites are closed during that time, does this mean Camping is not possible at all or are there other options (e.g camp outside the official sites?)

Answer (score 3):

Looked in the Chilean Ministry of Tourism site and they have a [touristic services](http://www.sernatur.cl/buscador-de-servicios) search where you can search for campings in specific regions os cities. Searching for *Torres del Paine* and *camping* gave me 4 results. Have you checked those camping sites?

There is a [site](http://www.torresdelpaine.com/ingles/) only about Torres del Paine including a [travel experience](http://www.torresdelpaine.com/ingles/secciones/noticias/19.asp) that might be of interest even though she used the *refugios*. I could not find any reason as to why would it *not* be possible to do the w-circuit in the date you mentioned.